# Recursive comparison of two strings

Tags: c++, recursion, c-strings

The function **int compare(...)**, checks if 2 strings are equal *ignoring* case and any non-alphabetical characters, e.g. "a?...!b" is equivalent to "ab". Returns 1 if equal, 0 else. However, there's a bug in my code!

```
int compare(const char* string1, const char* string2)
{
  if(string1 == NULL || string2 == NULL)
    return 0;

   std::cout << *string1 << " | " << *string2 << std::endl;
   if((!isalpha(*string1) && *string1 != ' ') && (!isalpha(*string2) && *string2 != ' '))
    {
      compare(++string1,++string2);
    }
   else if(!isalpha(*string1) && *string1 != ' ')
    {
      compare(++string1,string2);
    }
   else if(!isalpha(*string2) && *string2 != ' ')
    {
     compare(string1, ++string2);
    }

  if(tolower(*string1) != tolower(*string2))
    return 0;
  if(*string1 == '\0')
    return 1;
  if(*string1 == *string2)
    compare(++string1, ++string2);
}
```

If I try and run this code with for example:

```
compare("a !!!b", "a b");
```

The output really confuses me:

```
a | b
  | 
! | 
! | 
! | 
b | b
^@| ^@
  | a
^@| ^@
  | a
```

It returns 0 (not equal). It doesn't stop running once it gets to **b | b**, why?

Comment: You need to put `return` before each call to `compare`, otherwise it will recursively call `compare` but then continue executing the function.

Comment: Note that the use of `<ctype.h>` functions with `char` values will result in undefined behavior when the `char` values is negative! You should cast the `char` values to `unsigned char` before passing them to any of the functions from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: In addition to what @JohnnyMopp mentioned: there is no `return` statement at the end of the function: falling off the end of a function returning something different than `void` without a `return` statement is undefined behavior.

Comment: When you recursively invoke "compare()", your code is discarding the return value.

Comment: How can recursion occur if there are return statements before all calls to `compare`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp could you please clarify; because If I return 0 or 1 before the function call to `compare` the program finishes to early, and it doesn't make much sense to me, because only the first letter of the strings are checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides needing the `return` statement you have a flaw in your logic. You need to check if both strings are empty and thus equal earlier in the function:

```
int compare(const char* string1, const char* string2)
{
    if(string1 == NULL || string2 == NULL)
        return 0;

    // This needs to go here
    if(*string1 == '\0' && *string2 == '\0') {
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << *string1 << " | " << *string2 << std::endl;
    if((!isalpha(*string1) && *string1 != ' ') && (!isalpha(*string2) && *string2 != ' '))
    {
        return compare(++string1,++string2);
    }
    else if(!isalpha(*string1) && *string1 != ' ')
    {
        return compare(++string1,string2);
    }
    else if(!isalpha(*string2) && *string2 != ' ')
    {
        return compare(string1, ++string2);
    }

    if(tolower(*string1) != tolower(*string2))
        return 0;
    if(*string1 == *string2)
        return compare(++string1, ++string2);
}
```

You can check it here: https://ideone.com/Si78Nz